# Docker : Opensearch refuses connection with the example in opensearch documentation in docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, opensearch

I'm running opensearch v 1.0.0 on docker container with the following command on the `localhost`. Please consider this question **IS NOT** same as this post, [Opensearch Docker Image Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72644761/opensearch-docker-image-failed-to-establish-a-new-connection-errno-111-connec) since the cause of the failure is different.

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9600:9600 -e "discovery.type=single-node" opensearchproject/opensearch:1.0.0
```

I'm trying to run the code in the example in the opensearch [documentation](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/clients/python/) , **WITHOUT using ca_certs and ssl**.

```
from opensearchpy import OpenSearch

host = 'localhost'
port = 9200
auth = ('admin', 'admin') # For testing only. Don't store credentials in code.
# ca_certs_path = '/full/path/to/root-ca.pem' # Provide a CA bundle if you use intermediate CAs with your root CA.

# Optional client certificates if you don't want to use HTTP basic authentication.
# client_cert_path = '/full/path/to/client.pem'
# client_key_path = '/full/path/to/client-key.pem'

# Create the client with SSL/TLS enabled, but hostname verification disabled.
client = OpenSearch(
    hosts = [{'host': host, 'port': port}],
    http_compress = True, # enables gzip compression for request bodies
    http_auth = auth,
    # client_cert = client_cert_path,
    # client_key = client_key_path,
    use_ssl = False,
    verify_certs = False,
    ssl_assert_hostname = False,
    ssl_show_warn = False,
    # ca_certs = ca_certs_path
)

# Create an index with non-default settings.
index_name = 'python-test-index'
index_body = {
  'settings': {
    'index': {
      'number_of_shards': 4
    }
  }
}

response = client.indices.create(index_name, body=index_body)
print('\nCreating index:')
print(response)
```

And it gives me the following error.

```
ConnectionError: ConnectionError(('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end 
closed connection without response'))) caused by: ProtocolError(('Connection aborted.', 
RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))
```

After that I ran the following command on the terminal ,  It gives the expected output, which says that OpenSearch runs finely in docker.

```
$ curl -XGET https://localhost:9200 -u 'admin:admin' --insecure
```

How to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting `use_ssl=False`, but the `opensearch` Docker image appears to create an SSL server by default. You can see this if you watch the containers logs when you attempt to make a non-SSL connection:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record
```

If I modify your code to have `use_ssl=True`, then it runs successfully:

```
$ python opensearch_test.py
Loading .env environment variables...

Creating index:
{'acknowledged': True, 'shards_acknowledged': True, 'index': 'python-test-index'}
```

Comment: Yes actually `io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException` occurs. If I changed into `use_ssl=True` , Should I use CA certificate?

Comment: How do you set this if you're using a docker-compose?

Comment: This answer suggests a change to the Python code; you set it by changing the code. It's not related to any docker or docker-compose configuration.